# Google AppEngine proxy server cache vary by protocols

Tags: google-app-engine, protocols, reverse-proxy

What I would like to achieve is given the same url but different protocols:

```
http://myserver.com/path
https://myserver.com/path
```

Two different representations will be returned.

Currently, this two paths are cached by Google AppEngine proxy server that they basically can't tell the different, and will result in the same representation being returned.

I did some research on using vary header, but since the requests are coming directly from user browsers, that there is no way for us to add additional custom header.

Is there anyway that server can vary by protocols?

Comment: This is strange, different protocols means different urls which means that the cache MUST separate each url and not point to the same entry.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen it sounds right but not true in reality, at least not in the cast of Google AppEngine.